# How to define a storage outside the pallet?

Tags: storage

I recall there being a method to create a "const" storage outside of a pallet. You have the flexibility to assign any prefix. However, I can't remember where I came across this information. Could you please guide me on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind from your description is the `storage_alias`. It can have three different kind of prefix and can be declared outside of pallets (actually anywhere).

The standard version when a pallet storage should be addressed looks like this. It is useful for writing migrations from/to pallets:

```rust
#[storage_alias]
pub type PageIndex<T: Config> = StorageValue<Pallet<T>, PageIndexData>;
```

Now it is also possible to use another prefix, eg:

```rust
#[storage_alias(verbatim)]
pub type PageIndex = StorageValue<MyPrefix, PageIndexData>;
```

Or making it entirely runtime dependant such that it can change at any time. For example when `DynamicName` implements `Get<&'static str>`:

```rust
#[storage_alias(dynamic)]
pub type PageIndex = StorageValue<DynamicName, PageIndexData>;
```

Otherwise there is `parameter_types`, but it cannot take a custom prefix.

Comment: How does the `b":code"` work? Use sp-io to write the db directly?

Comment: Exactly. This is why it does not have any metadata. See the key definition [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a93858a8d80de838e54d286a820ea29d1a353746/primitives/storage/src/lib.rs#L195) and the write in [System](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/d347d68868a38841ba51f2e91cef945a7ea50dd4/substrate/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1107).  
This was done before any `storage_alias` existed.